# Velocity using #parse where the file doesn't exist

Tags: velocity, template-engine

we use Velocity to template our configuration files for several different environments and this process works really well but I have a quick question relating parsing a file that doesn't exist.

My question is:
How do you check if a file exists before parsing it?

So in the example the file default.user.properties might legitimately not exist and if it doesn't the rest of the file doesn't get parsed.

```
#parse("./default.user.properties")
```

I know one solution is to make sure the file is always there but it would be nice if I didn't have to.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Just did this with spring and velocity:

I had problems getting velocity to pick up my event handler, in the end specifying it in the servlet xml file:

```
<bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
        <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="WEB-INF/templates"/>
        <property name="velocityPropertiesMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="eventhandler.include.class"><value>com.velocity.events.OptionalIncludeEventHandler</value></entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

It simply would not accept me putting it in the properties file - it would instantiate the class, but not register it as an event listener. very frustrating.

The class itself is simple, a quite blatant rip off from the existing velocity class "org.apache.velocity.app.event.implementIncludeNotFound". The existing velocity implementation checks for the existance of the file, and if not present returns a configurable alternative (default: notfound.vm).

Mine is exactly the same except it returns null if the file does not exist, causing the parser to skip this include / parse directive:

```
public class OptionalIncludeEventHandler implements IncludeEventHandler, RuntimeServicesAware {

    private RuntimeServices rs;

    @Override
    public void setRuntimeServices(RuntimeServices rs) {
        this.rs = rs;
    }

    @Override
    public String includeEvent(String includeResourcePath, String currentResourcePath, String directiveName) {
        return rs.getLoaderNameForResource(includeResourcePath) != null ? includeResourcePath : null;
    }

}
```

Works like a charm.

Hope it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

A new type of event handler "IncludeEventHandler". This allows you, the developer, to define a class (implementing IncludeEventHandler) which will be called every time a #parse or #include is evaluated. The purpose of your event handler would be to check if the template exists and set an error flag for the calling code if not. 
Check the documentation for more information though I haven't tested it myself

Comment: Thanks for the answer the org.apache.velocity.app.event.IncludeEventHandler looks interesting although a bit more effort than I was hoping for, :)
It is also complicated as we merge/template the files all from ant so it is not clear how I will plug in the new implementation of IncludeEventHandler. But I will follow this up and post my findings.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I used is to create a utility method for checking template existence, i.e.

```
public synchronized boolean templateExists(String templateFilename) {
    Boolean templateExists = this.templateExistsCache.get(templateFilename);
    if (templateExists != null) {
        return templateExists;
    }
    String absoluteFilename = this.request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath(
            "/WEB-INF/templates/" + templateFilename);
    File templateFile = new File(absoluteFilename);
    templateExists = templateFile.exists();
    this.templateExistsCache.put(templateFilename, templateExists);
    return templateExists;
}

private Map<String, Boolean> templateExistsCache = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
```

from

https://github.com/okohll/agileBase/blob/master/gtpb_server/src/com/gtwm/pb/model/manageData/ViewTools.java